# SwiftUI ScrollView extra padding when go to another screen with showed keyboard

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview, keyboard-avoidance

The default "Keyboard Avoidance" SwiftUI is used.
[First GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6sIT.gif)

If you put the code in VStack and add another View to it, then the container rises
[Second GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTGeu.gif)

I don't want to delete Keyboard Avoidance. I need to remove extra spacing

scrollDismissesKeyboard for ScrollView is not an option

minimal iOS version is iOS 16

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = "Bu bu?"
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                VStack {
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Spacer()
                                .frame(height: 500)
                            TextField("", text: $text)
                                .padding(.bottom, 70)
                                .frame(height: 40)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .background(Color.red)
                            NavigationLink("Screen 2", destination: {
                                Text("SwiftUI - Nice to meet you, let's never meet again")
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    Text("I'm in VSTack after scroll view")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I looked it up with a hierarchy view, and noticed that a UIInputSetHostView is created with a height of 216
[View hierarchy 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ppPh.png)
[View hierarchy 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tutfO.png)

disableAutocorrection not working